# Create a slice plot of 3D velocity data in matlab

Tags: matlab, slice

I am trying to create a slice plot in Matlab. I receive an error that says "Error using interp3 (line 148). Input grid is not a valid MESHGRID. Error in slice (line 103) vi = interp3(x,y,z,v,xi,yi,zi,method);". The way it is set up, the vectors x,y,z, and u, will share the same size. I am not entirely sure how to resolve this error and would appreciate any input.

```
% Define the x, y, and z coordinates
x = 0:1.95313:1000;
y = 0:1.95313:250;
z = 0:1.93798:250;
[y,x,z] = meshgrid(y,x,z);
u = sin(x) + sin(y) + z;

% Define the slice planes
xslice = 0;
yslice = 0;
zslice = 0;

% Create the slice plot
slice(x, y, z, u, xslice, yslice, zslice);
view(3);
axis([0 1000 0 250 0 250]);
grid on;

shading interp;
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
zlabel('Z');
title('Slice Plot of 3D Velocity Vector');
```

Answer (score 1):

The mesh variables are swapped in your code. Define the grid in the order `x, y, z` and not `y, x, z`, as used later:

`[x,y,z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);`